# How do i load local files in filepond instance ? having problems

Tags: javascript, django, filepond

I'm building a forum using django, and i'm also using filepond to manage file uploads. I'm using the implementation django-drf-filepond (https://django-drf-filepond.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). I got everything working related to uploading files and serving them on my server, but i'm having trouble adding already uploaded files to a filepond instance (ex: a user wants to edit the post they made, along with the images they attached to it).

I'm using the 'files' option in my filepond instance with no success. I am able to navigate to localhost:8000/fp/load/?id=upload_id and i can see the image associated with that upload_id, so when i provide the link for the source i'm putting '?id=upload_id' but it's encoding the '?' and '=' and returns a 404 not found error, so example it's trying to get localhost:8000/fp/load/%3Fid%3Dupload_id and it's not working. i don't know what i'm supposed to put in the 'source' option for inital files to load. i've tried upload_id, full path to file, just the name of the file....i don't know what to do, and i don't know if django-drf-filepond is causing the problem or just me not knowing how to use filepond here.

i also saw that when i look at the stack trace, my request doesn't seem to be going through django-drf-filepond, but rather the filepond cdn files (their own load function?)

my filepond instance with 'files' option :

```
const inputElement = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]');
// Create a FilePond instance
const pond = FilePond.create(inputElement, {
    maxFiles: 3,
    maxFileSize: '2MB',
    acceptedFileTypes: ['image/*'],
    files:[{ source: '?id='+imageUrls[0].fields.upload_id, options: { type: 'local' }}]
});
```

error messages from python venv :
Not Found: /fp/load/4JveLP4mWAqudiKaqnc775
"GET /fp/load/4JveLP4mWAqudiKaqnc775 HTTP/1.1" 404 3809

django 404 response page :
Page not found (404)
Request URL : http://localhost:8000/fp/load/%3Fid%3D4JveLP4mWAqudiKaqnc775

LoadView from django-drf-filepond :

```
class LoadView(APIView):
    """
    Expect the upload ID to be provided with the 'id' parameter
    This may be either an upload_id that is stored in the StoredUpload
    table or it may be the path to a file (relative to the fixed upload
    directory specified by the DJANGO_DRF_FILEPOND_FILE_STORE_PATH
    setting parameter).
    """
    permission_classes = _import_permission_classes('GET_LOAD')

    def get(self, request):
        LOG.debug('Filepond API: Load view GET called...')

        if LOAD_RESTORE_PARAM_NAME not in request.GET:
            return Response('A required parameter is missing.',
                            status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        upload_id = request.GET[LOAD_RESTORE_PARAM_NAME]

        if (not upload_id) or (upload_id == ''):
            return Response('An invalid ID has been provided.',
                            status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        try:
            su = get_stored_upload(upload_id)
        except StoredUpload.DoesNotExist as e:
            LOG.error('StoredUpload with ID [%s] not found: [%s]'
                      % (upload_id, str(e)))
            return Response('Not found', status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

        # su is now the StoredUpload record for the requested file
        try:
            (filename, data_bytes) = get_stored_upload_file_data(su)
        except ConfigurationError as e:
            LOG.error('Error getting file upload: [%s]' % str(e))
            return HttpResponseServerError('The file upload settings are '
                                           'not configured correctly.')
        except FileNotFoundError:
            return HttpResponseNotFound('Error accessing file, not found.')
        except IOError:
            return HttpResponseServerError('Error reading file...')

        ct = _get_content_type(filename)

        response = HttpResponse(data_bytes, content_type=ct)
        response['Content-Disposition'] = ('inline; filename=%s' %
                                           filename)

        return response
```